# Styling a submit button for a Form in Laravel 4

Tags: css, forms, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to style a submit button for a form in Laravel 4.  However, when I try the following, I get the same old boring default button:

```
{{Form::submit('Submit', null, array(
'type' => 'button',
'class' => 'btn btn-large btn-primary openbutton',
));}}
```

Is there a special way to style this type of button in a form context?  Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17284985/how-to-add-classes-to-larvel-4-forms/17286473#17286473

Answer (score 17):

Try removing 'null' before the options array

```
{{Form::submit('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-large btn-primary openbutton'])}}
```

If you are just looking for a normal  html element try

```
{{Form::button('Open Image', ['class' => 'btn btn-large btn-primary openbutton'])}}
```

Comment: It should work, I use `Form::submit('Go', array('class' => 'btn'))` and it works fine.

Comment: hmm, well it is not working for me.  Any idea what may be going on?

Comment: Using something like this works fine: <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary openbutton" type="button">Open an Image</button>  but I am trying to use it with the Form submit button element

Comment: Is this only with submit and button?

Comment: yes it is only with the submit button that I am seeing this issue.

Comment: I updated the answer above, for a normal button use Form::button() as for a form submit button use Form::submit() let me know if it works.

Comment: If you do `Form::button('Open Image', ['class' => 'btn btn-large btn-primary openbutton'])` what is rendered in the browser? In the source.

Comment: This works, the styling is applied when done like this.  But will this work as the submit button for the form?  EDIT: It doesn't.  And when I use Form::submit, it doesn't apply the styling.

Comment: What does it render in the html source if you do `Form::submit('Open Image', ['class' => 'btn btn-large btn-primary openbutton'])`?

Comment: This renders the same boring button.  No styling.

Comment: Show me what it renders in the html source. Most likely somewhere your styling is overriding `input[type=submit]`.

Comment: <input class="btn btn-large btn-primary openbutton" type="submit" value="Open Image"></form>

Comment: This is not related to Laravel, as it renders exactly what is supposed to. You have to find what is reseting the input[type=submit] style. Make sure bootstrap.css is the last css being included in your views.

Comment: Even using my own CSS, when I just have class="button" (which I have styled), it doesn't work.

Comment: For me I thought it wouldnt work either.  The problem was the right parens needed to go after the class array, and not before.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this...

```
{{ Form::submit('Submit', array('class' => 'primary')), Form::reset('Clear', array('class' => 'secondary')) }}
```

Then in your css...

```
form input[type="submit"], form input[type="reset"] {
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px; border-collapse: separate !important;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

form input.primary[type="submit"] {
  clear: both;
  margin: 20px 10px 0px 10px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  width: 125px;
  height: 31px;
  background-color: #333333;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 31px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

form input.secondary[type="reset"] {
  clear: both;
  margin: 20px 10px 0px 10px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  width: 125px;
  height: 31px;
  background-color: #555555;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 31px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
 }
```

I hope this helps...